# I need to open an installed application on button click please do help me :]

Tags: android

I AM NOT able to post the code its saying like Code is not in format
Whatever
My question is "how to open an installed application on button click in android studio"

CardView HeyHello12;

```
    HeyHello12 = view.findViewById(R.id.Heyhello12);

    HeyHello12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            try {
                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using on Android 11 (Api level 30), you must have to include `<queries>` in your Manifest.xml file inside `<manifest>` tag.

```
<manifest ....>
    <queries>
         <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
    <queries>
    ....
    ....
</manifest>
```